# How to trigger jQuery in a reactive Environment?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, publish-subscribe, meteor

jQuery and Meteor

Meteor is reactive, born in a world of Web Apps where there is only one initial page load, jQuery was born in a world of server generated pages.

So, the question is… when to call a jQuery plugin on Meteor Templates?

1) On Page load ->
    Doesn´t work. The data isn´t there yet.

```
Template.contextualFeed.feedItems = ->
    Feed.find()
    $("abbr.timeago").timeago() # Calling the feed right away is useless as Feed.find() is initially empty and will populate a bit later when subscription is delivering the initial data.

<template name="contextualFeed">
    <ul class="feed {{isActive "feed"}}">
    {{#each feedItems}}
    <li class="popup-holder">
        {{> contextualFeedItem}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

2) On each Item->
    Works, but seems incredibly wasteful.

```
Template.contextualFeed.feedItems = ->
    Feed.find()

Template.contextualFeed.jQueryMe = ->
    $("abbr.timeago").timeago() # Works, but seems incredibly wasteful


<template name="contextualFeed">
    <ul class="feed {{isActive "feed"}}">
    {{#each feedItems}}
    <li class="popup-holder">
        {{> contextualFeedItem}}
        {{jQueryMe}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

3) Once after all items loaded ->
    Works, but is still not as elegant as it should be...

```
Template.contextualFeed.feedItems = ->
    Feed.find()

Template.contextualFeed.jQueryMe = ->
    Meteor.defer ->
        #(cut) some ugly code to make sure it only executes once.
        $("abbr.timeago").timeago() # Works, but seems incredibly wasteful


<template name="contextualFeed">
    <ul class="feed {{isActive "feed"}}">
    {{#each feedItems}}
    <li class="popup-holder">
        {{> contextualFeedItem}}
        {{jQueryMe}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

4) Isn´t there some event that fires when the Data is loaded not on every item seperately as an add?

So, do you´ve got a cleaner way of calling jQuery in Meteor Templates?

PS: The code examples are in Coffeescript... Be nice despite it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two potential trains of thought here. The idea that you propose in #4, a "dataLoaded" event might warrant some conversation. However, the first argument that comes to mind is that, as you rightly said, Meteor is of a new generation of fluid web app frameworks. In that world, what does it mean exactly that the initial set of data has loaded?

The second might be that there's a better solution to your problem. There may definitely be cases where the merging of jQuery and Meteor feels clunky, but after a cursory read of your example code I feel like there might be a better way in this example. It looks like you have a Feed collection and want to display a living timestamp for each feed item like "2 hours ago". Is that correct?

If so: I don't *think* that example #2 is terribly wasteful if you aren't going to store the living timestamp as its presented in Mongo. I'm admittedly not sure of the best way in Meteor, but you should be able to cache the timestamp value in the app. Another thing you might want to consider is storing the value in Mongo separate from the Unix timestamp - say, a number of hours. You could have a process running on the server to update the time elapsed on the feed item. This is sustainable assuming that the feed items eventually go stale, there aren't a huge number of them and you don't need to be super exact on the timestamp.

I don't have any data and don't suggest that these methods are a) right and b) faster than the obvious solution, but its food for thought.

---

ETA: Meteor.subscribe might be of use http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe. See the usage in the todo example: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/examples/todos/client/todos.js

Comment: Hey theresaanna, yea, I´m trying to use a jQuery plugin that converts the date/timestamp into "2 hours" ago. In example 2 the jQuery initialization code will be basically called within the loop, once per feed item, which seems a bit of an overkill...

Comment: thanks for your answer... it got me thinking and adding a callback to subscribe really is a thing I should give a try... in the past framework I´ve been using there simply was a way of binding a event to the Collection so that it could notify other parts of the app when it was loaded... maybe I´ll find something like that in the source...

Answer (score 0):

From the beginning of `wordplay/client/wordplay.js`, one of the Meteor examples:

```js
Words.find({player_id: Session.get('player_id'), state: 'bad'})
    .observe({
        added: function (word) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#word_' + word._id).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                    Words.remove(word._id);
                });
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
);
```

You don't need your templates to trigger your JS logic. Just use [.observe](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe).

Comment: Thanks for that :). I´ve been using observe but added triggers once for each item on load which seemed a bit to much for my (global) jQuery code...

Comment: Yeah, it's not meant to insert triggers.